# Transferred and resource CSS file sizes

Tags: css

I opened two sites
https://www.apple.com/shop
https://www.lenovo.com/

on apple site, landingpage.css is 34.6KB transferred size and 411KB resource size.
on Lenovo site, core.css is 44.2KB transferred size and 289KB resource size.

Lenovo site resource size is smaller than apple by 122KB, but the transferred size is bigger about 10KB?

I tried on my own site and same environment two css and I noticed the same issue, I have:
Css1 size: 400KB, transferred  89KB 
Css2 size: 780KB, transferred  70KB 
I used brotli compression for both files

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Resource compression

Web servers use **gzip** to reduce the total amount of data transferred to clients. When a browser with gzip support sends a request, it adds “gzip” to its Accept-Encoding header. When the webserver receives the request, it generates the response as normal, then checks the Accept-Encoding header to determine how to encode the response. If the server supports gzip, it uses gzip to compress each resource.

It then delivers the compressed copies of each resource with an added Content-Encoding header, specifying that the resource is encoded using gzip. The browser then decompresses the content into its original uncompressed version before rendering it to the user.

- Size Difference After Encoding

The difference of transfer sizes comes to the fact that one resource might be more compressible due to the nature of its content, if it's more compressible that means it generally contains more repetitive characters when considering **lossless** compression as our case. This comes to how encoding works.

- More Resources

[gzip Compression - pingdom](https://royal.pingdom.com/can-gzip-compression-really-improve-web-performance/#:~:text=Web%20servers%20use%20gzip%20to,to%20its%20Accept%2DEncoding%20header.&text=The%20gzip%20application%20uses%20level,favoring%20higher%20compression%20over%20speed.)

[Character encodings - W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)